# How do I control spacing within a Wordpress page that I am editing?

Tags: css, wordpress, spacing

Very simply, how do I control spacing between objects on a Wordpress page?

Specifically, I am attempting to remove the whitespace between the green boxes in the image below:

Screenshot: http://goo.gl/doZve
Page: http://bellairecabinets.com/new/

I would like the image with the phone number (top) to connect to the form (bottom). I checked the CSS that applies to the form and there is no margin. There is also no breakspace in the HTML code or the Wordpress WYSIWYG.

Why the white space?

Also, when entering wrong info and clicking submit, you receive an alert above the form. This moves the entire layout down. How can I fix this? Is there a way to simply change the alert to appear in a popup box instead of on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The white space is due a `margin-bottom: 15px;` present in the paragraph element inside the `div` with class `video-sub`. The paragraph also has a `line-height` of `20px`.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.video-sub p
{
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To align the green box with the slideshow, do this:

```
.video-sub
{
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

For a CSS popup, you can do this:

```
.form-error
{
    background-color: white;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I think you can replace the above code with this one that will take care of the error and form sent messages:

```
#contact-form-4758
{
     background-color: white;
     left: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 10px;
     position: fixed;
     right: 0;
     top: 30px;
     width: 980px;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked great!

only issue I have is that the green box is not aligned with the slideshow to the left of it. 

Any quick fix for this?

thanks!

Comment: Wow. You're awesome!So simple... yet I'm struggling with all this.

One last thing. Is it simple to make it so that the error pops up in a  popup box? Try clicking submit without entering anything and you will see what I mean. It ruins the layout...

Comment: Thank you. So sorry to bug you, but do you see which class I need to edit for the success message?I've been looking around and cannot tell which to apply to the same code you previously sent me to.

Comment: Not quite, that moved the entire form. Simply reload the page and check out what that did...

Comment: You still have the `.form-error` class applied. Remove it and replace that code with `#contact-form-4758`. See that I wrote replace above in the answer. :)

Comment: Hi Leniel, I did that, then reverted back. Just put it the way you said again, to double check.

Prior to asking you, I tried adding another class titled "form-sent" and added a div tag to where I thought it would go in the PHP, see the screenshot I sent :) thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, sort of... Only part of the Success message goes into the "pop-up". The rest, which is the info which the user entered (name, phone, etc) gets listed and replaces the form, so the interface is sort of off.

Not really sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Extra spacing in WordPress content is often caused by the WordPress automatic paragraph code.  This is a function named wp_autop(), its purpose is to add HTML breaks paragraphs where line feeds occur in the input. There are ways to turn it off or make it only apply when wanted.  Search the WordPress forums or autop.